# Counting norms on an infinite dimensional vector space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, real-analysis, norms

It is known that whenever E is a finite dimensional real vector space, there is only one norm on E up to equivalence (actually one non discrete vector space topology).

Is it known what happens when E is infinite dimensional? for sure, one can create two (infinitely many) non equivalent norms by using Hamel bases(*), but what about the precise cardinality (up to equivalence, or without taking into account equivalence at all) ?

(*) E.g. Let (e_i) a Hamel basis, write x = sum x_i e_i and  put 
||x|| = sum of |x_i|
N(x) = sum of i|x_i|

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at the papers "Über Normtopologien in linearen Räumen" ([Link to the article](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01899266)) as well as "Über vollständige Normtopologien in linearen Räumen" ([Link to the article](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01900215)) by D. Laugwitz.

He proves the following. Let $E$ be a vector space, denote by $a(E)$ the cardinality of a Hamel basis of $E$ and denote by $n(E)$ the number of mutually non-equivalent norms on $E$. Then

$$n(E) = 2^{a(E)}, \quad\text{if}~\mathfrak{c}\leq a(E),$$
$$ \mathfrak{c}\leq 2^{a(E)} \leq n(E) \leq 2^{\mathfrak{c}}, \quad\text{if}~\aleph_0\leq a(E)<\mathfrak{c},$$

and (of course)

$$ n(E) = 1 \quad\text{if}~1\leq a(E) < \aleph_0.$$

Here $\aleph_0$ denotes the cardinality of countable sets and $\mathfrak{c}$ the cardinality of the continuum. In the second article you can find the answer for complete norms.

Comment: Thankns a lot: I'll read attentlively these articles (as soon as I can get them. It answers perfectly my answer! an interesting case seems to be when the dimension $a(E)$ is $\aleph_0$.. I was assuming that such a normed space was second countable, though, ans thus that $n(E) = \mathfrak{c}$, by writing such a space as a countable union of finite dimensional (therefore seonc countable) spaces. Thanks again!

Comment: Can anyone provide me English translation of those two articles? I don't know that language.